# Scalar product, undefined matrix multiplications and order of operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am curious about the order of operations in linear algebra. Let $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B}\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$, with $m\neq n$ and $\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v} = \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

1. How do I motivate $(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{B}\mathbf{u})\cdot \mathbf{v} = \alpha \mathbf{A} + \alpha\mathbf{B}$? By order of operations is the addition carried out first, but the matrix multiplications $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{B}\mathbf{u}$ are not defined.
2. A similar problem arises with $\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{v}\, \mathbf{A} = \alpha\mathbf{A}$. Once again is not the product $\mathbf{v}\mathbf{A}$ defined, due to dimensions. Does the scalar product always have priority when it comes to order of operations?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

(1) The meaning
$$
(Au+Bu)\cdot v = \alpha A + \alpha B
$$ 
is highly confusing, and is pretty much illegal anyway: The parentheses already indicate a certain order of execution of the multiplications - first $Au$ and $Bu$, then times $v$. But $Au$ and $Bu$ are not defined - FAIL

(2) Is trickier:
$$
u\cdot v A = (u\cdot v)A.
$$
Here, one should see that $vA$ is undefined, so the meaning of the expression must be 
$$
u\cdot v A = (u\cdot v)A.
$$
There are proofs, where one uses that $u\cdot v$ is a real number, thus commutes with any other object.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I agree with your arguments, but these expressions are present in an article I am reading. They may be wrong, or at least not so strict, but I would like to understand if (1) is motivated in any sense.

Could one not use the same argument in (1) as in (2), that the operations must be carried out in a specific in order to make the expression valid?

$\mathbf{A}\alpha + \mathbf{B}\alpha = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{v} + \mathbf{B}\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{v} = (\mathbf{A}\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{B}\mathbf{u})\cdot \mathbf{v}$?

Answer (score 0):

You could not calculate $Au+Bu$, because the dimensions do not agree, you would at least need $A,B\in\Bbb R^{m\times n}$, but then $Au+Bu\in\Bbb R^m$, so now we cannot take the inner product, so from the start you would need $A,B\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$.

Now $(Au+Bu)\cdot v\ne (A+B)(u\cdot v)=\alpha(A+B)$

This because $(Au+Bu)$ is a vector, so $(Au+Bu)\cdot v$ is a scalar, not a matrix.

The reason $u\cdot vA=\alpha A$ is because the operation $vA$ does not hold (since the dimensions do not agree), so it is implicitly assumed that,

$u\cdot vA=(u\cdot v)A=\alpha A$

Comment: Thank your for the response. Please see my comment at daw's post.